# AVSpeechSynthesizer: how to display in a default player view

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avspeechsynthesizer, avspeechutterance

I use `AVSpeechSynthesizer` to play text books via audio.

```
private lazy var synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer = {
    let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
    synthesizer.delegate = self
    return synthesizer
  }()

let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: text)
    utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(
      language: languageIdentifier(from: language)
    )
    synthesizer.speak(utterance)
```

I want to update information in iPhone's default player view (probably naming is wrong ):

[image]

- indicate playing Chapter with some text
- enable next button to play the next chapter

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Is the player connected to the speech at all? Does it pause it, or show its progress? If not, you cannot influence it at all. Synthesized speech is not a "song".

Comment: @matt thank you for the answer. Aren't there any workarounds? should I start a "silent song" to accomplish it? are there any way to update information in this players info view? I mean even for songs I suppose there is a way how the developers sets information in this view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't think you want to hack your way through this.. But if you really do I would:

- Listen to remote commands (`UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()`, see [Apple Sample Project](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/becoming_a_now_playable_app)
- Set your properties on `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter`: `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] = "Title"`
- Implement the `AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate` and try to map the delegate functions to playback states and estimate the playback progress using `speechSynthesizer(_:willSpeakRangeOfSpeechString:utterance:)` (idk if possible)
- You might have to play with the `usesApplicationAudioSession` property of `AVSpeechSynthesizer` to have more control over the audio session (set categories etc.)